# How can I do action without any content in web forms?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a file only for deleting my objects but it will only delete something and then redirect to source page not needed to show any content (only needs `Page_Load`).

For this goal is any type that can I use instead of regular `aspx` type that have not content part?

Comment: I would go with service or at least page method then use AJAX to invoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .ashx, the handler. You can view a tutorial here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Answer (score 0):

try this 
put your pageload event code in
public static method

```
    public static void MethodName()//pass parameter if required
    { 
        //do your work here ;
    }
```

after that you can directly access this method from whatever your page

Comment: I want to have some thing like `aspx` but without content.